# Conditional iteration in a single job in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am working on an iterative algorithm using Apache Spark, which claims to be perfect for just that. The examples I have found so far creates a single job with a hardcoded number of iterations. I need the algorithm to run until a certain condition is met.

My current implementation launches a new job for each iteration something like this:

```
var data = sc.textFile(...).map().cache()
while(data.filter(...).isEmpty()) {
  // Run the Algorithm (also handles caching)
  val data = performStep(data)
}
```

This is pretty inefficient. Between each iteration I wait a long time for the next job to start. For four servers I wait around 10 seconds in between each job, for 32 servers is almost 100 seconds. In total I end up spending at least half of the runtime waiting in between jobs.

I find conditional iterations quite common in certain types of algorithms, for example early stopping criteria in machine learning. So I am hoping this can be improved.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this? For example away to run this conditional repetition in a single job? Thanks!

Comment: Could elaborate a little? Code you've provided shows only one job with multiple stages. Do you mean that you're waiting for `data.filter(...).isEmpty()` or is there something else going on here?

Comment: Of course.  I think this is what is going on: When `isEmpty` is called  a spark job is launched and my code waits until it is complete. When that job is complete my code continues into `performStep` and builds the next job (this is an extension of the first job). This will be sent to my slaves executed in the next `isEmpty` call. While this is happening no job is running and my cluster is idling.

Comment: You could mitigate the waiting time by only checking every 10th iteration, for example, whether you algorithm has converged or not.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is really nothing wrong with a general structure. You can check `MLlib` [`GradientDescent`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/optimization/GradientDescent.scala#L220) which is doing pretty much the same thing. I tried to reproduce the problem ([here is a gist](https://gist.github.com/zero323/7cc5fede0b3a8e3a6878)). "Expensive" version shows "waiting-like" behavior but it looks like a matter of data collection.